# Why does nvidiafb module hang the entire system?

Tags: linux, nvidia, kernel-modules

I have an older `P5K` asus mobo with:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation GT218 [GeForce 8400 GS Rev. 3] [10de:10c3] (rev a2)    Subsystem: eVga.com. Corp. Device [3842:1302]
```

that hangs (the entire system) if `nvidiafb` module (from kernel `6.6.5`) is loaded.   I found https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-1044092-start-0.html but that is related to the `drm` driver.

I'm wondering if there is a way around this other than blacklisting or removing that driver?  And why do the nvidia drivers hang so many systems?

TIA!!

Comment: AFAIK `nvidiafb` is deprecated and terribly outdated and for FB/KMS you need to use either `nouveau` or binary nvidia drivers. And, yes, blacklisting this module is the best thing to do. This has nothing to do with *"nvidia drivers hang so many systems"*.

Comment: How would you tell it to use nouveau for the frame buffer, i see it for drm.   It was included in the 6.6.5 kernel build with that option (chipset level items) enabled.

Comment: https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/nvidia-framebuffer-support-needed-nvidia-geforce-gtx-760-a-4175599267/ You really shouldn't be using nvidiafb in 2023

Comment: I asked a whole new question at: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/764769/how-does-this-whole-framebuffer-drm-kms-stuff-work-in-todays-linux-kernel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nvidiafb` which has long been deprecated must be disabled or blacklisted and `nouveau` should be used instead.